# How to update a value in directly vector of vector in java EE

Tags: java, vector, insert-update

I have vector (vector of vector) named reviewDataWithHeader[1].

i can access its value in first vector at location 3 as string as given below.

```
String status= ((Vector) reviewDataWithHeader[1].get(0)).get(3).toString();
```

then after some operations 
i got `status = "xyz"`

I want to update the status value directly in vector of vector `(reviewDataWithHeader[1])`

My trials are like

```
1.
reviewDataWithHeader[1].remove( ((Vector) reviewDataWithHeader[1].get(yy)).get(3)) ;
reviewDataWithHeader[1].insertElementAt( (Vector) reviewDataWithHeader[1].get(yy)).get(3), status) ; // error

2.
reviewDataWithHeader[1].setElementAt( status, (Vector) reviewDataWithHeader[1].get(yy)).get(3)) ; //error
```

Comment: Post some small example. See http://www.sscce.org/. Also, post your actual errors.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the fact that you really should encapsulate this behind a class instead of operating on lists of vectors of vectors, and the fact that you should use ArrayList instead of Vector, the following should work:

```
reviewDataWithHeader[1].get(yy).set(3, status);
```